# Translating a div to the right and have it disappear behind an invisible line

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, transform

Alright so the way i asked the question isn't the greatest because I'm not too sure on how to even explain what I'm trying to figure out.

https://jsfiddle.net/ff9ovhvp/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100">
  </div>
</div>

.row{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width:500px;
}
img{
  transition: 3.5s;
}
img:hover{
  transform:translateX(500px);
}
```

If you look at the code I posted above, I'm trying to have that placeholder image disappear as it passes through the right border. Not have it phase out or disappear all at once but have it seem like it is being pushed behind a wall or a barrier, sort of like a little pocket and then have it slide out of there once the cursor is no longer hovering the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an animation, not merely a transition.

I also would base the animate upon the hover state of the image parent div, not the image itself. If you base hover events on the image, and the image moves... that means the cursor position can (and will) alter the transition/animation because the image moves under the cursor... so it is 100% possible for the image to move so "hover" is no longer true.

```css
.row{
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width:500px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #ccc, inset 0 0 35px #ddd; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  /* hide overflow of container div */
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* set image holder to 100%% width of parent */
.imgHold { width: 100%; position: relative; left:0; }
img { display: block;}

/* animate the IMAGE on hover of the parent div
   this prevents the hover state causing the
 animation to be "jerky" because the image
 moves under the cursor. */
.imgHold:hover img{
 position: relative;
  animation: toRight 2s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes toRight {
 from { left: 0%;}
 to { left: 110%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="imgHold">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Pet Peeve: Do **not** name classes and ID the same as standard HTML tags. It's bad practice and only causes confusion should editing in the future be required.</sub>

```css
.row{
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width:500px;
  background: #eee;
  margin: 10px; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #ccc, inset 0 0 35px #ddd; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  /* hide overflow of container div */
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* set image holder to 100%% width of parent */
.imgHold { width: 100%; position: relative; left:0; }
img { display: block; position: relative; left: 0%;}

.imgHold:hover img{
 position: relative;
  left: 105%;
  transition: left 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="imgHold">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Any reason why the animation and not the transition? Also I changed the hover over to my div that contains the image rather than the image itself and it made the movement a lot less jittery, thanks for that. I'll also make sure not to name my classes and ID's the same as HTML tags next time, I was just rushing while posting the question so I needed something simple.

Comment: I added a snippet if you really want to use transition. I merely prefer animation in many cases due the more more specific control over certain aspects. But for something simple like this, a transition may be fine. More personal preference than anything.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `overflow: hidden;` CSS property to the `.row` element to make it go behind the `.row` div.

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkrcpowf/1/) or have a look at the code below

```css
.row {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Just add this property */
}

img {
  transition: 3.5s;
}

img:hover {
  transform:translateX(500px);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `overflow:hidden` to your `.row` and it works fine.

```css
.row{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width:500px;
  overflow:hidden; /*Add this*/
}
img{
  transition: 3.5s;
}
img:hover{
  transform:translateX(500px);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100">
  </div>
</div>
```